# Decreasing begin() iterator and then increasing it again

Tags: c++, c++11

Are such statements valid by the standard?

```
std::string str{"123"};
auto it = str.begin();
--it;
++it; // Does *it point to character '1' now?
```

I've tried this on g++ 4.7.2 and clang++ 3.5 - `*it` returns `'1'`.
Is this the standard behavior in c++11?

Comment: Try debug checks: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c72499373b8d2fb

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No, it is not valid.

It is undefined behaviour, as 24.2.6 [bidirectional.iterators] states that a postcondition of `--it` is that the result must be dereferenceable. As it points before `begin()` in your example, this condition is not met and hence the code is illegal.

As there is no diagnostic required it *might* seem to work, but you can not (and should not) rely on it.

Comment: Shouldn't the reasoning be the other way round?  The *pre*condition is not met as there is no `s` before `r = begin()` such that `r == ++s`.  Therefore, the operation is not permitted.

Comment: @5gon12eder There are multiple ways to look at it and reason about it. I used the postcondition as it seems most obvious to me, along the thought that if you decrement an iterator, it must still point to a valid location. YMMV.

Comment: @5gon12eder: either reason puts the expression in undefined behavior.  Also note that even for raw pointers the behavior of `--` is undefined if the pointer starts out pointing to the first element of an array or to an object that is not an element of an array.

Comment: For those who may disagree (this answer is not intuitive for some), I will point out that in many cases, because of how many iterator types happen to be implemented as pointers, and how pointers happen to be implemented on most platforms, you usually get lucky and it works.  While this may be the case, it is still undefined behavior.  You are simply getting lucky if it happens to work for you that day.  I recommend lotto tickets!