# Is the sequencing of this decrement invoking undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, stl, containers, undefined-behavior, erase

I am looking for confirmation, clarification is this code well defined or not.

It is very common to erase elements of a container in a loop by re-assigning the iterator to the result of the container's `erase()` function. The loop is usually a little messy like this:

```
struct peer { int i; peer(int i): i(i) {} };

int main()
{
    std::list<peer> peers {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    for(auto p = peers.begin(); p != peers.end();) // remember not to increment
    {
        if(p->i > 1 && p->i < 4)
            p = peers.erase(p);
        else
            ++p; // remember to increment
    }

    for(auto&& peer: peers)
        std::cout << peer.i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output:** 0 1 4 5 6

It occurred to me that the following might be little tidier, assuming it is not invoking undefined behavior:

```
struct peer { int i; peer(int i): i(i) {} };

int main()
{
    std::list<peer> peers {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    for(auto p = peers.begin(); p != peers.end(); ++p)
        if(p->i > 1 && p->i < 4)
            --(p = peers.erase(p)); // idiomatic decrement ???

    for(auto&& peer: peers)
        std::cout << peer.i << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

**Output:** 0 1 4 5 6

The reasons why I think this works are as follows:

- `peers.erase()` will always return an incremented `p`, therefore it is safe to decrement it again
- `peers.erase(p)` makes a *copy* of `p` so it will not operate on the wrong value due to sequencing [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase)
- `p = peers.erase(p)` returns a `p&` so the decrement operates on the correct object [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable).

But I have niggling doubts. I am worried I am invoking the bad sequencing rule by using `--(p)` in the same expression where `p` is used as a parameter despite the fact that it looks on paper to be okay.

Can anyone see a problem with my assessment here? Or is this well defined?

Comment: I would stick with the first version - it is more readable for a start

Comment: There's no problem sequencing-wise because these are overloaded operators - i.e., function calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on the condition that you are using to detect those elements to delete. It will fail if you try to delete the first element as `erase` will return the new `begin()` and you are then decrementing it. [This is illegal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29054751/2073257), even if you immediately increment it again.

To avoid this error and because it is more common and readable, I'd stick with the first version.

Comment: Yes, I have just checked up on this and its definitely disallowed in the standard.

Answer (score 2):

Second version is - as stated by @DanielFrey - wrong, but if you don't like first version, why just not do something like that:

```
std::list<int> myList = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

myList.remove_if(
    [](int value) -> bool {
        return value > 1 && value < 4;
    }
);

/* even shorter version
myList.remove_if([](int value) -> bool {
    return (value > 1 && value < 4);
});
*/

for(int value : myList) {
    std::cout << value << " ";
}
```

This gives output:

```
0 1 4 5 6
```

[Live example](http://ideone.com/PBN9em).

Comment: This is a good idea. Unfortunately sometimes you want to do a number of different things depending on different conditions - sometimes erasing, sometimes calling member functions etc.... In those cases you need to do the loop yourself.

Comment: @Galik - (1) OP's example was all about removing specific items so... ;) (2) **Take a look at [that](http://ideone.com/lXKJBE) - you can modify values too.** Just return true if this value is to be removed and return false if this value is not to be removed. Otherwise this acts pretty good as container iterator with custom fucntion called for each item.